# OpenLDAP TLSv1.2 configuration

Tags: linux, ssl, configuration, openldap, ldif

I am trying to set up my OpenLDAP to only use TLSv1.2 and better and I am trying it with this ldif:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSProtocolMin
olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.3
```

But when I try to import it I get the following:

```
# ldapmodify -vvv -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ./tls-only.ldif
ldap_initialize( ldapi:///??base )
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
add olcTLSCipherSuite:
    HIGH
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

I don't get it and can't find a solution.

PS: I already successfully imported the TLS Certs...

Answer (score 0):

First You are trying to modify two components do add a connecting character "-".

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH
-
add: olcTLSProtocolMin
olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.3
```

Secondly if you face some issue for TLSCipherSuite , Try following vales for enabling TLS 1.2 only.

SECURE256:-VERS-TLS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.2:-RSA:-DHE-DSS:-CAMELLIA-128-CBC:-CAMELLIA-256-CBC:-SHA1